# ORDER BY column not in the GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to run this query in elastic sql, I am trying to group by processsing time, but its not allowing me to do. I tried putting this table as subquery and then ordering, it fails again to order.

```
SELECT tId, pType, MIN(InTime) FirstIn, MAX(OutTime) LastOut, 
       COALESCE(CAST(MAX(OutTime) AS NUMERIC) - CAST(MIN(InTime) AS NUMERIC),-1) processingTime_ms 
FROM "logstash*" 
where tId not like '.%' and tradeId is not null 
group by tId, pType
order by processingTime_ms DESC 
limit 500
```

I tried ordering with the complete expression, it gives the same error of CANNOT ORDERBY COLUMN OUTSIDE GROUP BY. Tried butting this entire result in subquery and then ordering, It doesn't give error but it doesn't also sort. Kibana canvas doesn't have a sort on dataframe so I am stuck with sql the only option to sort the data.

Comment: Ordering on non-grouped column is not allowed. Check https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/30585

Comment: What underlying database are you using?  Almost all databases support column aliases in the `ORDER BY` -- some even require using them.  You can, of course, repeat the expression if your database does not support this.

Comment: Its elastic sql, they have an open bug regarding this as pointed by jaspreet